# How to create multiple objects for a range of dates on RoR?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, simple-form

I'm working on a booking project where I have an `offer` with a range of days. Each day, a `user` could create a `slot` with a different `schedule`. After creating an `offer`, a `user` has to define the `slots` for everyday including in the `offer`.

I'm working on rails 5.2.1

This is my code :

```
controller
slots_controller.rb

  def create
    @user = current_user
    @offer = Offer.find(params[:offer_id])
    all_start = @offer.start_date
    all_end = @offer.end_date
    @days = (all_start..all_end).map{ |day| day.strftime("%b %d") }
    @slot = @offer.slots.new(slot_params)
  end

  def slot_params
    params.require(:slot).permit(
      :day,
      :schedule_id,
      :offer_id
      )
  end
```

```
view
/slots/new.html.erb

<div class="container">
  <% @days.each do |day| %>
    <%= simple_form_for ([@offer, @slot]) do |f| %>
      <div class="wrap">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-sm-6">
            <div class="service">
            <%= f.input :day, collection: @days %>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-sm-6">
            <div class="service">
              <%= f.input :schedule_id, collection: Schedule.all %>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <%= f.button :submit, "Créer mon roulement", class: "btnmarginb btn-primary" %>
    <% end %>
  <% end %>
</div>
```

Models :

```
offer.rb
  has_many :hours
  has_many :schedules, through: :hours, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :slots
```

```
schedule.rb
  has_many :hours, dependent: :delete_all
  has_many :offers, through: :hours, dependent: :delete_all
  has_many :slots, through: :offers
```

```
slot.rb
  belongs_to :offer
  belongs_to :schedule
```

With this code, the form is duplicated. 
I tried to iterate in the controller, in the views, read the doc (https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Persistence/ClassMethods.html#method-i-create), but not really understand if I have to iterate in the view or in the controller to do that : 
`# Create an Array of new objects
User.create([{ first_name: 'Jamie' }, { first_name: 'Jeremy' }])`

I'm expecting to get `@offer.slots.create` with one form.
Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do? You are trying to have one form with all the days in it? Right now you are iterating over each day and creating a form for each day. It looks like you need to take that @days.each away and not iterate over those. That creates one form.

Comment: Exactly, I'm trying to have one form with all the days in it. By the way, the user could save : `day : 1, shedule_id : 2 ; day : 2, schedule_id: 6` for example.

Comment: So you have a User, Schedule, Offer, and Slot. How does the Schedule, Offer, and Slot relate? Does an offer have one schedule? And a schedule has many slots? I am not really following your logic yet.

Comment: I added my models. A schedule `belongs_to company` and `has_many` `offers` and `slots`- An `offer` `has_many schedules` and `has_many slots`. A `slot` `belongs_to offer` and `belongs_to schedule` Did I make a mistake between `offer` and `schedule` or forget a `join_table` ?